# Unstable training of BERT binary sequence classification. Higher loss but lower gradients

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient-descent

I'm training a BERT sequence classifier on a custom dataset. When the training starts, the loss is at around ~0.4 in a few steps. I print the absolute sum of gradients for each layer/item in the model and the values are high. The model converges initially but when left to be trained for a few hours and sometimes even early as well it gets stuck. I am calculating gradients with the below code. Also the logs are at - https://pastecode.io/s/v2s3mr3e (initial convergence) . I'm printing gradients, loss, metrics and logits.

```
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    print(name, param.grad.abs().sum())
```

While the model is stuck, the loss value is around ~0.69 with worse performance metrics (precision/recall) on the training set but the gradients are very small compared to the initial training phase. Also it seems that predictions are swinging with most of the values predicted as either 0 or 1. Following are the logs for the stuck phase - https://pastecode.io/s/cjuxog44

Training code Link - [Training Code](https://gist.github.com/thesillystudent/56046463cdc4da9dfa8ba13bc02cd5da)

It seems that the model is stuck at a local minima where the gradient values are relatively smaller even though the loss is high. How can I mitigate it ? One option I see is using a higher learning rate or a cyclic learning rate but not sure if that's the right approach since the the learning rate is 5e-5 with LR scheduler disabled. Below is the plot for Loss, Bert pooler and classifier gradients sum over steps.

Also the data is 50-50 balanced. Batch size is 32. I'm using AdamW. I have also tried SGD but the convergence is very slow.

Or there might be some error/reason which I am not able to identify. Please help

[image: Plot for Loss, Bert pooler and classifier gradients sum over steps]

Comment: Do you also have a validation set? If I read it right, the loss in the plot is the training loss. Having also loss and metrics on a validation set would indeed help to assess the situation.